# Update models in EF core after DBA change database schema

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

I need to update my models from database but keep all DataAnnotations in my models because all validations use them and when i force Scaffold-DbContext my database all of DataAnnotations will gone.

Our company is old, As our database, We have a 20 years old database and it will use in more than 40 app, So **we can't use EF core migration system and it's our DBA task to update database schema**, But in our new project we want to use EF core 3.1.18 so we need keep update our models from our master database which control by our DBA.

I find this command for update our models :

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=OurServer;Database=OurDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Force -d
```

This is our custom model after first generated by Scaffold-DbContext command :

```
[Table("tblUser")]
public partial class TblUser
{
    [Key]
    [Column("intUserID")]
    [DisplayName("UserID")]
    public long IntUserId { get; set; }

    [Column("intUserGroupID")]
    public byte IntUserGroupId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please enter name of the user")]
    [Column("strName")]
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string StrName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the username for login")]
    [Column("strUserName")]
    [DisplayName("Username")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string StrUserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a password for the user")]
    [Column("strPassword")]
    [DisplayName("Password")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string StrPassword { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(IntUserGroupId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(TblUserGroup.TblUser))]
    public virtual TblUserGroup IntUserGroup { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see we add **Required** and **DisplayName** attribute to our models, In some classes we have even custom attribute for our fields.

After we use the command Scaffold-DbContext with -Force parameter all of our DataAnnotations with be deleted like this :

```
[Table("tblUser")]
public partial class TblUser
{
    [Key]
    [Column("intUserID")]
    public long IntUserId { get; set; }

    [Column("intUserGroupID")]
    public byte IntUserGroupId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("strName")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string StrName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("strUserName")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string StrUserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("strPassword")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string StrPassword { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(IntUserGroupId))]
    [InverseProperty(nameof(TblUserGroup.TblUser))]
    public virtual TblUserGroup IntUserGroup { get; set; }
}
```

The **Required** and **DisplayName** attribute are used in whole app but we lose them every time our DBA change the database and we need to update models.

Probably we are not only company which have DBA and all databases are managed by them, So what is the solution?

**EDIT :**

I tried to add metadata as @PanagiotisKanavos said, But it seems metadata not working in EF core Scaffold-DbContext command, Here it is the class i add in project (All these class are in same namespace) :

```
[MetadataType(typeof(TblUserMetadata))]
public partial class TblUser
{
  
}
public class TblUserMetadata
{
    [DisplayName("User ID")]
    public long IntUserID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("UserGroup ID")]
    public byte IntUserGroupID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter name of the user")]
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string StrName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the username for login")]
    [DisplayName("UserName")]
    public string StrUserName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a password for the user")]
    [DisplayName("Password")]
    public string StrPassword { get; set; }
}
```

But the result is still same, All custom attributes are gone after Scaffold-DbContext command.

Comment: The extra attributes are about validation and display. Since 2010 at least it's possible to put all those rules in a [metadata class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/enhancing-data-validation#add-metadata-classes) that ASP.NET recognizes and applies during validation or display. What kind of application are you building? ASP.NET MVC? Core? Razor Pages?

Comment: We are using ASP.NET core blazor serverside

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried metadata after you mention it, It seems it's not working in EF core Scaffold-DbContext command but it worked in EF 6 in design mode. Is there any trick to use metadata in EF core Scaffold-DbContext?